# Get a value using PY3 & BS

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following code:

```
<div class="offer-wrapper">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="fixed breakword  ad_ideYpjG" summary="Anunt" data-id="221265704"
```

I want to scrape the **data-id** value using Python and BS.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken your data as html from that you can find main div and from that get table tag using `get` method you can extract required attribute of that tag

```
html="""<div class="offer-wrapper">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="fixed breakword  ad_ideYpjG" summary="Anunt" data-id="221265704">"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
main_div=soup.find("div",class_="offer-wrapper")
print(main_div.find("table").get("data-id"))
```

Output:

```
'221265704'
```

Comment: Try with `for a in soup.find_all("div",class_="offer-wrapper"):` beacuse it gives you list of elements